# running sudo apt update error gives Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, update-manager

```
sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Ign:6 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease                             
Hit:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Hit:9 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Get:10 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release [815 B]                      
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu cosmic InRelease   
Hit:12 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic InRelease   
Hit:14 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease
Hit:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:16 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease     
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                       
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu cosmic InRelease           
Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
Hit:20 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu cosmic InRelease      
Err:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu cosmic Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                       
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/sylvain-pineau/kazam/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I'm mostly concerned about Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]

i've tried changing `archive.ubuntu` in sources.list to `old-releases.ubuntu` and that did not help

Comment: Seems like expected behavior for End-of-Life releases.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.10 (CosmicCuttlefish) was supported for 9 months until July 2019. If you need Long Term Support, it is recommended you use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS instead.

See `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CosmicCuttlefish/ReleaseNotes' for more details.